# Retrain best model on full dataset in R

Tags: r

I have two models to select from and using some criteria I choose one of the two. (The below is just an example, I know it doesn't make much sense)

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(4)
sample_dat= sample(1:nrow(cars), 5)
train = cars[-sample_dat, ]
test = cars[sample_dat, ]
models = list(lm(dist ~ speed, train), glm(dist ~ speed, train, family = "poisson"))
test_res = sapply(models, function(x) accuracy(predict(x, test, type = "response"), test$dist)[2]) #Getting the RMSE for each model
best_model = models[which.min(test_res)]
```

How can I retrain the best model using the full dataset (train + test)? I checked the `update` and `update.formula` functions but these don't seem to be updating the data part.

Comment: Many models contain an expression of the call, so you could mess with that and pass it to `eval`, but that's slightly ridiculous. Probably better to save a list of functions to create the models, then `lapply` it to create `models` here, and then subset to the function you want once you've selected and call it again.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. I tried `model_list = list(glm, lm)` and then 
`retrained = model_list[[which.min(rest_res)]](dist ~ speed, data = cars)` which works for the lm model. How would you pass the family = "poisson" argument though?

Comment: you should use `update`:   `update(best_model[[1]],data = rbind(train,test))`

Comment: Yup that does it, thank you! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update(best_model[[1]],data = rbind(train,test))
```

You do not want to change the formula since that is the best model but rather update the data

Answer (score 1):

Base R using your own logic, first creating a list mirroring the models list:

```
set.seed(4)
sample_dat= sample(1:nrow(cars), 5)
train = cars[-sample_dat, ]
test = cars[sample_dat, ]
models = list(lm(dist ~ speed, train), glm(dist ~ speed, train, family = "poisson"))
model_application = list(as.expression("lm(dist ~ speed, cars)$call"), 
                         as.expression("glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family = 'poisson'))$call"))
test_res = sapply(models, 
                  function(x){
                    # Store a function to caclulate the RMSE: rmse => function 
                    rmse <- function(actual_vec, pred_vec){sqrt(mean((pred_vec - actual_vec)**2))}
                    # Getting the RMSE for each model: numeric scalar => .GlobalEnv
                    rmse(test$dist, predict(x, data = test, type = "response"))
                  }
)

best_model = models[[which.min(test_res)]]
applied_model <- eval(eval(as.expression(parse(text = model_application[[which.min(test_res)]]))))
```

Comment: Thank you but this trains all the models on the whole dataset. This is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: @User2321 try this, a bit messy but delays execution until explicitly evaluated.

Comment: @User2321 please upvote and accept my answer if you find it useful and/or meets your needs otherwise please tell me if you’d like me to make any changes